# How to create a direct upload script like pipebytes.com?

Tags: php, upload, p2p

Has anyone an idea how pipebytes.com works ? I need to implement similar system in PHP and I do not know how to start. The only thing I know is that it is possible to implement it :). Please help!

Comment: How *does* pipebytes.com work?

Comment: The pipebytes.com allows client - client upload that does not need to use any FTP server. I just need a similar script. Maybe something like PHP p2p client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Update: Pipebytes are indeed not an ordinary filesharing service because *they start serving the file before it is completely uploaded*. Still, the principle is the same. Their server receives the file, and serves it to the recipient. It is *not* p2p.

Looks pretty straightforward to me. The "file is *sent* to the recipient" is slightly misleading, as far as I can see there is no real peer-to-peer process involved here. The file is stored on their server, and delivered to the recipient if they manage to enter the correct code.

Steps:

- File upload (manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php))
- Storing the file somewhere in the filesystem
- Storing the code specified by the user somewhere, e.g. a database
- Sending an E-Mail to the recipient (manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php))
- Serving the file to the recipient (related questions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547005/save-remote-file-that-pushes-headers-to-force-download))

Comment: I don't think it is a proper solution. If there is f.e. more than 10 000 users of the system the server can be easily overloaded.

Comment: @Kamil then you buy more servers.

Comment: @Kamil this is the way pipebytes.com works, there is no p2p involved. Plus, thousands of sites serve files this way, with far more than 10.000 users. They just buy, as @zaf says, more powerful hardware with the growing demand.

Comment: quotation from pipebytes.com: "Unique P2P file exchange service."

Comment: @Kamil it's not really true. I just tried it out. The data stream goes to their server and back. Even if the upload takes place in "real time" it's still a program *on the server* that handles the incoming file, and serves it to the recipient as a normal file download from their server. This is *not* real, direct peer-to-peer traffic period.

Comment: @Kamil - the site in question is using `peer to peer` inappropriately, as marketing jargon and not a factual statement of how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Pipebytes is not your normal file sharing service like Pekka describes.

What happens is that the client uploads to the server and at the same time the receiver downloads the file byte by byte.

The server is basically transmitting the uploaded file back to another user.

This is not a P2P. The server is required. You can read what the definition for P2P here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer