# echo the contents of a File to the user but make it act as a download

Tags: php

I have a script where I get the contents of a file and then echo it to the screen, the problem is that it actually echos the binary file to the page, what I want if for it to act like a download where the download dialog will display.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save remote file that pushes headers to force download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547005/save-remote-file-that-pushes-headers-to-force-download)

Comment: Did any of the duplicate close-voters actually read that question? This isn't the same question *at all*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the PHP [header()](http://www.php.net/header) manual:

```
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
```

Change the content-type and the filename. You can user readfile over file_get_contents, but either or should work.

Answer (score 2):

You use the unofficial but ubiquitously supported `Content-disposition` header. See the first example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/rar.examples.php). There are a few quirks in browser support for the filename.

You could also simply change the `Content-type` header to `application/octet-stream`, but then you can't suggesta a filename to the user without more complex mechanisms.

(Note: `application/binary` is perhaps an option that's better than `application/octet-stream` because "If Content-Type matches one of generic values, such as application/octet-stream [...], many browsers treat this as a permission to second-guess the value based on the aforementioned signals, and try to come up with something more specific. The rationale for this step is that some badly configured web servers fall back to these types on all returned content." Source: [Google Browser Security Handbook](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2)).

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the Content-Type of the HTTP response.

In "raw" PHP (ie. without use of any framework), it would look like:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
```

It is necessary to invoke it at the beginning of the script, before any of the data is echoed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Brad for the answer. i have done some modifications in it. What i found is if my content is echoed than no need to do "readfile". What i have done is.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="download.pdf"');
$pdf = $thirdPartyAPI->getPdf($ID);
echo $pdf;
ob_clean();
flush();
exit;
```